# how do you do if statement on a text in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am calling an api end point to get the env where the hosts are located as this:

```
 #server array

hosts=["server1", "server2", "server3"]

#given each host, I have to located where they are located as this:
for host in hosts:
    try:
        firstUrl="http://example.com/searchhost/"
        searchUrl=firstUrl+host
        resp = requests.get(searchUrl, params="-s")
        search_table = pd.read_html(resp.content)
        df = search_table[0]
        env=df['Environment'][0]
        #this part works, I am able retrive where the servers are or I get "Not Found" text. If the server is "Not Found", I should go the next server and so on.
        #this part is not working, even though, I get "Not Found", it is still moving along. How do I break out of the loop if env is not "Not Found"
        if env != "Not Found":
            hostIdUrl="http://test.com/host
```

Comment: With the `break` statement.

Comment: Is your goal to stop looking at the other endpoints? or skip the one that is not found?

Comment: @bcstryker skip the one not found

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to skip the case where env is "Not Found", then this code is your fix

```
if env == "Not Found":
    continue
hostIdUrl="http://test.com/host
```

however if you want to stop looping entirely, then this is your fix

```
if env == "Not Found":
    break
hostIdUrl="http://test.com/host
```

I feel I should point out that you must use the value of `hostIdUrl` in the iteration of the loop where it is assigned value as it will only hold the value of the last string assigned to it on the last iteration once the looping is done.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_continue_statement.htm